# cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-boot

I am working on a spring boot application. I want to achieve sending some json data to a web api. When I try to run it, the following error comes up. After so many attempts, its not getting resolved. Any help will be much appreciated:

*Error console:*

```
2017-03-31 12:00:36.634  WARN 2972 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'oniSavingsApiController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'oniSavingsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'oniSavingsApiService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'readSheet'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.oni.excelReader.ReadSheet' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
2017-03-31 12:00:36.634  INFO 2972 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2017-03-31 12:00:36.654  INFO 2972 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-03-31 12:00:36.798 ERROR 2972 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

Description:

Field readSheet in com.oni.service.OniSavingsApiService required a bean of type 'com.oni.excelReader.ReadSheet' that could not be found.
```

---

*Application*

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.oni.controller, com.oni.service")
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

*Controller*

```
@Controller
public class OniSavingsApiController {

    @Autowired
    private OniSavingsApiService oniSavingsService;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public void home() {
        oniSavingsService.oakRestCall();
    }
}
```

*Service*

```
@Component
public class OniSavingsApiService {

@Autowired
private ReadSheet readSheet;

public static final String CUSTOM_INFO = "custominformation";
public static final String AUTHORIZATION = "Basic";

public void oakRestCall() {

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.set("Authorization", AUTHORIZATION);

    ArrayList<ResponseEntity<ResponseData>> responses = new ArrayList<ResponseEntity<ResponseData>>();
    List<ExcelFields> listOfExcelData = readSheet.getFileContent();

    for (ExcelFields ef : listOfExcelData) {
        System.out.println(ef.getId());
        try {
            String json = "";
            String urlString = "";
            /**
            some code here
            **/
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Place your `Application` in  in `com.oni` and remove the `@ComponentScan` or add the `com.oni.excelReader` to the `@ComponentScan`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ComponentScan` scans only `com.oni.controller` and `com.oni.service` packages to inject the dependencies, so change it to scan through the whole "com.oni" package as shown below:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.oni")
```

or the other option is include `com.oni.excelReader` package (in which your `ReadSheet` class is located) as well:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.oni.controller, 
                           com.oni.service, com.oni.excelReader")
```

**P.S.:** If you **move your `Application` class to `com.oni`, you don't need `@ComponentScan` at all**, **Spring boot automatically scans all sub-packages of `com.oni`** for you.

Comment: moving 'Application' class to 'com.oni' puts it in default package and this is not allowed.
** WARNING ** : Your ApplicationContext is unlikely to start due to a @ComponentScan of the default package.

Comment: seems like you are trying to place it inside `src/main/java`, simply try `@ComponentScan` other options shown above

Comment: yes, adding `com.oni.excelReader` helped. Thanks man!
The application has started but I am facing this error when I hit localhost from my browser:
**Whitelabel Error Page**
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.